# How to create a jlist with images

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jscrollpane, jlist

I want to add some images to my jlist. following code works great

```
public class MarioList {

private final Map<String, ImageIcon> imageMap;

public MarioList() {
    String[] nameList = {"Mario", "Luigi", "Bowser", "Koopa", "Princess"};
    imageMap = createImageMap(nameList);
    JList list = new JList(nameList);
    list.setCellRenderer(new MarioListRenderer());

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(list);
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(scroll);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public class MarioListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    Font font = new Font("helvitica", Font.BOLD, 24);

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list, Object value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(
                list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        label.setIcon(imageMap.get((String) value));
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.RIGHT);
        label.setFont(font);
        return label;
    }
}

private Map<String, ImageIcon> createImageMap(String[] list) {
    Map<String, ImageIcon> map = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        map.put("Mario", new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCsHu.png")));
        map.put("Luigi", new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvHN4.png")));
        map.put("Bowser", new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/s89ON.png")));
        map.put("Koopa", new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEK2o.png")));
        map.put("Princess", new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4T4l.png")));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return map;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MarioList();
        }
    });
}
}
```

above code creates a new frame and add a jscrollpane to it. Instead of that I tried to create the frame and jcrollpane mannually using Netbeans. So instead of this code;

```
JList list = new JList(nameList);
    list.setCellRenderer(new MarioListRenderer());

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(list);
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(scroll);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

I used this code;

```
jList1.add(nameList);
    jList1.setCellRenderer(new MarioListRenderer());
```

Here jList1 is my jlist created via Netbeans and it has been put in a jscrollpane.
but this code doesn't work.
Please tell me a way to get this work... Thank you

Comment: Start by getting rid of `scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));` and consider using something like [`JList#setVisibleRowCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount(int))

Comment: I created jlist and jscrollpane using Netbeans. So I don't need to create those things again & frame also. When I remove those things; it doesn't work!

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* - What does that mean?  Doesn't compile, doesn't show up the screen, doesn't appear the you wanted?  If you've the scroll pane and frame, then it won't show on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Java 7+...

```
jList1.add(nameList);
```

Should be

```
jList1.setListData(nameList);
```

Otherwise you will need to wrap the `nameList` within a `ListModel` implementation